# Why does a program started by a batch file using command start not run while it runs via Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
::Checks if there is a JRE installed
start "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\ConfCompiler\Tools\CheckJre.exe"
```

When I copy and paste the file location above into Windows Explorer it works fine. But the program does not run from the batch file I have created.

The purpose of `CheckJre.exe` is to create new keys inside of HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

The keys are created when I simply run it from Windows Explorer. But the keys are NOT created when running it from the batch file. The batch file just results in displaying a command prompt window with showing `CheckJre.exe` with full path in title bar.

Does anyone have a hint why?

Comment: Is `%USERPROFILE%` set in the environment from which your batch file is run?  Do you get any error messages?  Is `::` valid syntax for a batch file?

Comment: @jeffamaphone, '::' is valid, it indicates a comment, just like how '//' does the same in Eclipse or VisualStudios. 
'%USERPROFILE%' is valid as well, all my other methods like copy and move work fine. And if I write 'echo' before the start line '%USERPROFILE%' is displayed as the correct path.
And I do not get any error messages

Comment: Do you have permission to launch executables?

Comment: @JustSid, do I need permission to launch an executable from windows explorer?
Because it launches fine from windows explorer.

Comment: @izhodzis Does the shell and Explorer have the same permissions? Genuine questions, I'm not a Windows user.

Comment: @JustSid I am not sure to be honest. I do not know how to check permissions and I do not know what a 'shell' is. (I also am quite new to this). When I run an executable from the .bat file, it opens a blank Command Prompt with the path as the header. Does that give an indication to it working or permissions?

Comment: @izhodzis Like I said, no idea. But does it work when you right click and select "Launch as Administrator"?

Comment: @JustSid, It does NOT work when I select Run as Administrator, but it DOES when I simply double click it. (For the .exe in windows explorer, not the .bat).

Comment: @Mofi, I probably should have mentioned that. I will put that in the question above so others who view this can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `start` interprets the first double quoted string as title for the command line window to open. For all options of command `start` enter in a command prompt window either `start /?` or `help start`.

You need to explicitly specify a title in your batch file because of the double quoted string to run `CheckJre.exe`.

Use in batch file:

```
start "Check JRE" "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\ConfCompiler\Tools\CheckJre.exe"
```

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you so much Mofi! 
(and JustSid and jeffamaphone for your input)
I would vote up your answer but I have too low a reputation -_-

Comment: @izhodzis Got you covered with the upvote! Sorry for not being more of an help, I should stay away from questions that I as an OS X user can't answer!

Comment: @JustSid it's ok. Thank you for your input either way :)